# How do we enforce a bidirectional interface with a Java Interface?

Tags: java, interface, private, observer-pattern

Java does not allow private or protected methods, so how do we ensure implementors of a bidirectional interface call the necessary methods?

Let's say we have an IModelListener interface as follows:

```
public interface IModelListener
{   
    public void handleChannelUpdate(int channel);
}
```

Then we have a ViewControl client as follows:

```
public class ViewControl implements IModelListener
```

ViewControl objects are going to work as long as we remember to have ViewControl call this:

```
model.registerChannelListener(this);
```

If Java allowed protected or private methods in an Interface, we could simply modify IModelListener to:

```
public interface IModelListener
{   
    public void handleChannelUpdate(int channel);
    private void registerChannelListener( );
}
```

How can this be achieved?
Are there annotations that would do this?

Java does not support multiple inheritance so if Clients/Implementors are already a derived class (typical), then using an abstract class is not an option.

Thanks for helping,
Jeff

Comment: if you want to implement some functionality, use abstract class instead interface

Comment: Although it is highly subjective, very few projects in Java adopt the Hungarian notation for classes and interfaces (as opposed to C#).

Comment: Yes, I am aware of this.  Sometimes I break the rules.  I just feel leading "I" greatly improves readability.

Answer (score 3):

You probably miss the concept of interfaces. It can not contain private or protected methods, because the role of an interface is to provide accessible set of methods. You probably might, on the other hand, take look at abstract classes.

What you need is probably this:

```
public abstract class AbstractViewControler implements IModelListener {

    protected abstract void registerChannelListener();

    protected AbstractViewControler() {
        this.registerChannelListener();
    }
}
```

and then:

```
public class MyViewControler extends AbstractViewControler {

    protected void registerChanelListener() {
        //- Do what you need here.
    }
}
```

and after that just:

```
IModelListener listner = new MyViewControler();
```

Comment: I do think it reasonable for an interface to have protected methods as part of the interface. Not my fault the java designers didn't ask me. :)

Comment: What would be the reason for it? If you want to model certain aspects of descendant classes which are not supposed to be available for everybody, then use abstract classes. You can, for instance, place invoking of abstract methods in this abstract class constructor and just implement these methods in your descendant class. That's probably what you wanted to achieve with private/protected methods in interfaces.

Comment: Let's say you want all implementing classes to have a getFooDancer() method that it would implement in it's own way. I've wanted this a couple of times over the years, maybe just for testing. I'm just saying I can see protected some, although private is clearly ridiculous.

Comment: Then if it were protected, who would call it? On the other hand you can force it (to have an internal method called by the class itself) by extending an abstract class --- vide update to the original answer.

Comment: Granted, but then that takes your only inheritance.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but generally it is a problem of single inheritance in Java --- I'd rather hesitate to call specifically a problem with Java interfaces. 8)

Comment: OK. But it was interfaces we were discussing and I was bitching about that. ;)

Answer (score 1):

An interface is a way of providing a public contract to users of the class implementing the interface. How the class is implemented doesn't matter, as long as they are adhering to the contract. Therefore, it doesn't make sense to have private methods in an interface.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to enforce a default behavior on your class - in Java, abstract classes are the place to formulate default behavior inherited by all extending classes (see the template method design pattern for an application of this). Interfaces only describe, how your objects externally behave and how they can be used by others.

Answer (score 0):

Interface in java intended to provide the signature of interface functionality in mean of signature that you implement in your classs so it should not to be private.

your need: you can have abstract method with some default statements that you want.

where you can have all type of access specifire.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, you can't do it using an interface only.

If you want to achieve some sort of "autobinding" (i.e. call `model.registerChannelListener(this);` automatically on all pertinent objects), then you should have those objects implement an empty interface, retrieve the list of all the instances of classes implementing it via introspection and iterate on them.

You could do this periodically or at some specific point in the program. You could also use an @interface annotation to add a little syntactical sugar.

You might also want to invert the flow and create objects using dependency injection and/or a factory, so that you have that method called "automagically" just after creation (like with `@PostConstruct`).

Comment: Thank you Stefano for taking the time to understand the question, and not assuming I'm a noob who doesn't know what an interface or abstract class is.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces are the wrong place to look.

The usual solution in Java for problems like this one is to have a method in either object which returns the other:

```
public class ViewControl {
    public IModel getModel() {...}
}
```

The method can then make sure that the model and the view are correctly hooked up. Now I guess that you don't really want to couple the view and the model. The solution is then to define a new `ViewModel` type which just delegates to the real model (most IDEs allow to create delegate types with 3-5 mouse clicks):

```
public class ViewControl {
    public ViewModel getViewModel( IModel model ) {...}
}
```

You should be able to move this code to a base (`abstract`) view class which all views inherit from.